# Trying to run a previous code and add those results to my current code using %Include

Tags: sas, macros, dataset, compare, proc-sql

I have a code saved in a folder that produces results - let's reference the results as results A.

I have another set of results, but have saved these as Results B in a folder.
1.
I am currently working on a code that helps me compare data fields from results A and B.

I have used the %include statement to direct to Results A code
I have another statement that looks like this:
%JK(JK.ResultsB, ScoreMatch);

Data Parity;

Set ScoreMatch;

Parity = Automated_Score - Calculated Score;

If Parity = 0 then ScoreMatch = 1;

Else ScoreMatch = 0;

SAS doesn't recognise my %JK statement (this is something I've gotten from another person's code in the team - not sure what it does) I'm a newbie with SAS and trying to understand how I can connect the results to get my final results which includes the comparison

Answer (score 0):

%JK(JK.ResultsB, ScoreMatch); is a macro call. You have to use %include statement for that macro as well (or some other way of loading that macro into your setup). But you should definitely check the JK macro code, so you at least get the general idea of what it does.

Comment: Hmm, there is no JK macro code that I can find. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Ask your colleague, author of your %JK call for it. If you want to call a macro, that macro has to be either run in the same program before the macro call, be included by %include statement, or you can store them permanently  using store option inside a macro statement.